# Combobox no muestra los items correctamente

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, pero no logro que me muestre los items normalmente, me los muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código que estoy usando:

```
        IEnumerable<Estatus> es = new Estatus().GetAll();
        estatusBindingSource.DataSource = es;
        cbStatus.SelectedIndex = -1;
        foreach (var item in es)
        {
            elcbEstatus.Items.Add(new { Text = item.Descripcion, Value = item.idEstatus });
        }
```

que es lo que me falta, no lo hago de la otra forma porque no me muestra nada, solo con este código logre que me mostrara la lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas intentando añadir al `ComboBox` **objetos anónimos**. Deberías crear objetos del tipo `ComboBoxItem`de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public object Value { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Text;
   }
}
```

Y luego añadirlos al `ComboBox` así:

```
    IEnumerable<Estatus> es = new Estatus().GetAll();
    estatusBindingSource.DataSource = es;
    cbStatus.SelectedIndex = -1;

    foreach (var item in es)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
        item.Text = item.Descripcion;
        item.Value = item.idEstatus;

        elcbEstatus.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: y para seleccionar el valor de la variable value cuando seleccione un item?

Comment: Indícalo mejor en una nueva pregunta. También amplía mas el código del Form, como por ejemplo que es estatusBindingSource, etc.